# How to update a SQL Server table id with unique key constraint?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table and I want to update all the ID = 2 to ID = 1 provided the dates are different because there is a constraint on the `Date` column, it should be unique.

[image]

I'm using this code but don't know how to update it with such a constraint.

```
update table
set ID = 1
where ID = 2
```

Is there a way to group by these dates and if the count(date) > 1 then do not update the table?

I'm expecting this output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `NOT EXISTS` condition to exclude those rows from update whose date  exists with ID = 1.

```
update T1
set T1.ID = 1
From MyTable T1
where T1.ID = 2
AND Not Exists (Select 1 from MyTable T2 Where T2.Id = 1 and T2.Date = T1.Date)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using join

```
CREATE TABLE T
(
  ID INT,
  [Date] DATE,
  Amt INT
);

INSERT INTO T VALUES
(1, '2018-07-17', 450),
(1, '2018-07-18', 500),
(1, '2018-07-19', 600),
(2, '2018-07-17', 850),
(2, '2018-07-18', 950),
(2, '2018-07-19', 900),
(2, '2018-07-20', 380),
(2, '2018-07-21', 920);

UPDATE T1
SET T1.ID = 1
FROM T T1 INNER JOIN
          (
            SELECT MAX(ID) ID, [Date]
            FROM T
            GROUP BY [Date]
            HAVING COUNT([Date]) = 1
          ) T2 ON T1.[Date] = T2.[Date]
WHERE T1.ID = 2;

SELECT *
FROM T;
```

Comment: I thought of doing something like this but I need to change ID=1 ONLY, I know I have just mentioned 2 IDs in my question but that was just an example. Originally I have a lot of IDs in my table. Thank you so much though. :)